# WinUI 3 XAML DataTemplate - how to include a control exposed by the class used for binding

Tags: xaml, controls, datatemplate, winui-3

I have a WinUi 3 desktop app. It contains a Grid control named "mainGrid". It contains a Grid.Resources element as follows:

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HorizontalMobTemplate" x:DataType="local:Mob" >
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="AliceBlue"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Label}" FontSize="16" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <StackLayout x:Name="HorizontalStackLayout" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="8" />
    </Grid.Resources>
```

In code I have a class called Mob with various properties, including a string property called Label and a Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid property called MyGrid.

The Grid contains a ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewer1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                  MaxHeight="50">
        <ItemsRepeater 
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind MobItems}" 
            Layout="{StaticResource HorizontalStackLayout}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HorizontalMobTemplate}"
         />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

So far, so good -- the Scroll viewer shows the Label property of each Mob object in a nice horizontal scrollable repeater. But that's not really what I want. I want to insert a reference to the Mob.MyGrid property, which is a Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid. Something like this:

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HorizontalMobTemplate" x:DataType="local:Mob" >
            <PULL IN THE Mob.MyGrid PROPERTY HERE />
           
        </DataTemplate>
        <StackLayout x:Name="HorizontalStackLayout" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="8" />
    </Grid.Resources>
```

In other words, I want my XAML to insert a child element that is the MyGrid control exposed in my Mob.MyGrid property. What syntax do I need to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ContentControl` that binds to the `Grid` property:

```
<ContentControl Content="{x:Bind MyGrid}" />
```